# Compute a date range in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantics

The query

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Event]] 
| ?name | ?datefrom | ?dateto
}}
```

returns a table with two dates in separate columns, for instance *21 May 2011* and *28 May 2011*.

Is there a way to get something like *21-28 May 2011* in one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'd have to pre-process the interval within each event page.

If you're using templates, the easiest thing that you can do is to create a semantic tag like this `[[dateinterval::{{{datefrom}}} - {{{dateto}}}]]`

If you want anything more elaborate like the `21-28 May 2011` you proposed, that will be more difficult and I can't find any extension to calculate date intervals.

Perhaps you'll have to write your own.